# Compile mapsforge jar files download from github - Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, jar, configuration, mapsforge

I've started a new project in android Studio because for me it seemed the most obvious thing to do, compile mapsforge so I can use it in my next project create an App .

**My first steps :**

1. Via Android Studio : File > New > Project from version control
2. Download mapsforge from Github : https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge.git

   - [After above steps this is my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoHQO.jpg)
3. Opened and take look at the existing build.gradle file... aaaaargh
4. Ignore the whole gradle stuff, just goto : Build > Make Project Ctrl + F9 ... executing taks and gradle build finished, no errors , Nice !

**Questions:**

1. Where is the path where the jar files are generated / copied to? How to configure it? In AndroidStudio OR ignore this and just focus on the gradle.build script?

**Note:**
It's not about programming or developing its about environment configuration.
So I really struggle with gradle, never used it before, started watching tutorials/demos, read stuff about it, ! I know rtfm ! Im missing out on some helpfull documentation.

I just want to compile and generate the jars (one time only) and use them in my App, thats it...

Comment: You are aware that this means doing things the hard way, right? If you want to update to a new mapsforge version you will have to do all those steps over (instead of just editing the number of the new version in your build.gradle when using gradle with maven central).

Comment: Yes I know, maven is outdated that's why... sample code uses changed and new added classes.